# Vue onBeforeRouteLeave won't work in production only

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

My SPA application has some bottom sheets components which I need to close them on back button and stay in the same page. my approach is working great in development environment but the issue is when I deploy the application into `Nginx` web server, `onBeforeRouteLeave` guard won't work as expected and changes the route url!

**do You have any idea that why it's not working in production?**

here is my navigation guard inside my component:

```js
onBeforeRouteLeave((_to, _from, next) => {
  if (referral.status) {
    referral.status = false;
    return false;
  }

  if (support.status) {
    support.status = false;
    toast.error(from.fullPath);
    return false;
  }

  if (exit.status) {
    exit.status = false;
    return false;
  }

  if (auth.status) {
    auth.status = false;
    return false;
  }

  next();
})
```

Comment: "onBeforeRouteLeave guard won't work as expected and changes the route url" - it's unknown how this happens. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem and describe what are the steps to reproduce. It's highly unlikely that you diagnosed the problem with onBeforeRouteLeave correctly because it's straightforward and behaves the same way in prod.